# How to read a memory address' value from an exe?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-address

So I am trying to output how many rings I have when I run `SonicAdventureDXPC.exe` via reading a memory address. I got the address where it stores the ring count but when I run the code it would always output `-1082988699` (even if the ring count was 1 or higher). This is the code I have:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
DWORD ADDR = 0x370F0E4;
DWORD PID;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    HWND Window = FindWindow(0, "SonicAdventureDXPC");
    if (Window == 0) {
        std::cout << "Can't find the window"<< std::endl;
    }
    else {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(Window, &PID);
        HANDLE Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
        if (Process != 0) {
            int Read_V;
            ReadProcessMemory(Process, (LPVOID)ADDR, &Read_V, sizeof(Read_V), 0);
            std::cout << "Rings: " <<  Read_V << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The code is actually correct but me being me made a very dumb tiny mistake. While troubleshooting with Cheat Engine, I found out that I made a typo in the address variable. It was suppose to be 0x03**B**0F0E4, not 0x03**F**0F0E4.

Comment: Check the return value of `ReadProcessMemory`.

Comment: `0x370F0E4` remember that windows randomizes the address on every single run: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: Assuming that the address is always correct, are you certain the ring count is stored as a (presumably 4 bytes) signed integer?

Comment: @molbdnilo It returns a 1

Comment: @Frank I am 100% sure that it's a 4 byte integer, since every time I run the game, the address is always a 4 byte integer (and has the ring count value) when I check with Cheat Engine

Comment: @Chinsman Then, though unrelated to the problem you are having, you should really be using `std::int32_t` or `std::uint32_t`. `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes (and a byte is not even forced to be 8 bits if you want to get real pedantic).